# Essential by something

Tags: sentence-meaning

> A group of proteins, summarised as the sarcomeric cytoskeleton, is essential for the ordered assembly of actin and myosin filaments into sarcomeres, by combining architectural, mechanical and signalling functions.

Does it mean that SC is essential for `assembly by combining` or it can also mean that SC is `essential by combining` for the assembly?

Comment: "Does it mean..." not "Is it means"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that SC is essential for the *ordered assembly of actin and myosin filaments into sarcomeres.*

The last part means that SC *uses the process of combining architectural, mechanical and signalling functions* to assemble the above into sarcomeres.

Comment: So the sentence doesn't imply that SC is essential for the assembly due to usage of the process of combining? Parts of the sentence are absolutely independent each of other?

Comment: It just says that SC does the combing, and uses it for the assembly

Comment: Wouldn't it then be better to rewrite the sentence to `... and combines architectural, mechanical and signalling functions`? I'm still confused by the usage of a `by` preposition here.

Comment: "by" simply means that it helps in the assembly using the process of combing.